# Proof of distribution $\chi_n ^2$?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

I have the problem of proofing that

$$X=(1/\sigma^2) \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i ^2$$

where $Y_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ is $\chi_n ^2$ distributed with $E(X)=n$:

My proof that $E(X)=n$:

$$E(X)=E((1/\sigma^2) \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i ^2)= $$
$$\sigma^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(E(Y) - \bar Y)$$

$$E(X)=E((1/\sum_{i=1}^{n}(E(Y) - \bar Y)) \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i ^2)= $$

here I am stuck and do not get the transition to $E(X)=n$

My question are:

How to get to $E(X)=n$?
How would you prove that $X$ is  $\chi_n ^2$ distributed?
Is is possible to imagine some range of numbers and draw it?

I really appreciate your answer!!!

Comment: If $Y_i\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ then $Z_i=\frac1 \sigma Y_i \sim N(0,1)$ and $X=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum (Y_i^2) = \sum (Z_i^2) \sim \chi^2_n$ by the definition of $\chi^2_n$

Comment: If $Y_i\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ then $E[Y_i^2]=\text{Var}(Y_i)+0^2=\sigma^2$ so $E[X]=E[\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum (Y_i^2)] = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum E[Y_i^2] = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}n\sigma^2=n$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the $\chi_n ^2$ distribution: this is a sum of the squares of $n$ (independent) standard normal variables (see e.g. [Chi-squared on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution)):
$$
X=(1/\sigma^2) \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i ^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (Y_i/\sigma) ^2
$$
You should have no problem proving that $Y_i/\sigma$ is standard normal and independence is obvious.

For the expected value, it's easiest (notationally) to start from the sum of squared independent standard normal variables ($X_i=Y_i/\sigma$). By the independence, the expected value of the sum is the sum of the expected values:
$$
E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{n} E[X_i^2]
$$
But we have for each $i$: 
$$E[X_i^2] = Var(X_i) + E[X_i]^2 = 1 + 0^2 = 1$$
So finally:
$$
E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1 = n
$$

Comment: THX for your answer! Would you be so kind to give me a hint on how to start proving that $X=(1/\sigma^2) \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i ^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (Y_i/\sigma) ^2$ is $\chi_n ^2$ distributed?

Comment: Ehrm. Sure. Read my answer from the start until "... is obvious."